# Specify the image index when we have multiple swipable images

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that contains a gesture detector and a card. In this widget I want to show some text information and one or more images.
There is something that I don't know the exact name, that shows the image index (For example, we have three images, so there are three small rectangles. We are on the second image, so the second rectangle has a different color or more opacity), I want to know how I can implement this in flutter and what its name is.
I have attached the image of that widget I need from a website, and also added my code. Thanks.

[image]

```
 GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
          setState(() {
            if (0 < widget.current_index) {
              widget.current_index--;
            }
          });
        }
        if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          setState(() {
            if (widget.current_index < number_of_photos - 1) {
              widget.current_index++;
            }
          });}},
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        child: Card(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        image: image(photoURL[widget.current_index]).image,
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown),)
            child: Text(id),
                  Text(
                        name,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),),),),)
```

PS: Using the links in the solution, I Used `AnimatedSmoorh` with this code, and it worked perfectly:

```
 AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
              activeIndex: widget.current_index,
              count: number_of_photos,
              effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called `indicators`, `page indicators`, `index indicators`, etc...

There is a package called [smooth_page_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator) that provides a customizable animated page indicator with a set of built-in effects.

Also you can check this [gallery](https://fluttergems.dev/carousel-cover-flow/) from [fluttergems.dev](https://fluttergems.dev/) to get a good number of `indicators` packages along with `Carousel` with built-in `indicators`.

Comment: How can I set the controller regarding to my code?

Comment: You can add the `indicator` in a `Stack` above the image and workaround with the index of the image with a controller.